# Message guarantees on rapidly updated entities in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'd like to understand how Firebase and listening Clients behave in the situation where a large number of updates are made to an entity in a short amount of time, and a client is listening to 'value' changes on that entity.

Say I have an entity in firebase with some simple data.

```
{
  "entity": 1
}
```

And the value of that "entity" was updated very rapidly. Something like the below code that writes 1000 integers.

```
//pseudo-code for making 1000 writes as quickly as possible
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   ref.child('entity').set(i)
}
```

Ignoring transient issues, would a listening client using the ['on' API in a browser](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) receive ALL 1000 notifications containing 0-999, or does Firebase have throttles in place?

Comment: What is `asyncWrite`? As far as I know, no Firebase SDK has that operation. Aside from that: Firebase will execute the operations you tell it to operate. So if you'd call `ref.child('entity').set(i);` in a loop, it will execute that set as many times (and indeed send as many updates to the Firebase servers). You can try it and check the Network tab of your browser's debugger to see them go.

Comment: I use the RESTful API and an async HTTP client. Hence the pseudo code. It's just a hypothetical situation, the updates could come from anywhere... I'm asking if the listening client will see ALL of the writes. Not if a javascript client will send all the requests lol

Comment: I've updated the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: If the listeners should act on every change, then you should not be setting the same value. You should instead be using `push` and `on('child_added'`. But you're using the REST API, where those are of course different. I suggest you change the question to include a real use-case ad an mcve. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is so complicated? The javascript API clearly states that you can listen for everytime the value changes. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html If i wrote an incremented integer each time then the value would change 1000 times. I want to know if my client will see each new value, even if the value is changed very quickly. My client is the javascript API in a web browser.

Comment: I don't think a mcve is necessary because it's a hypothetical question about how Firebase and listening clients will behave in a certain situation. That situation is when a large number of updates are made to an entity in a short amount of time, and a client is listening for all 'value' changes to that entity.

Comment: If you're looking for a listener to acknowledge every "change", then each change apparently has its own meaning and thus should be a separate child node (hence using push instead of set). This is regardless of whether Firebase will send every update. There are way more things that can go wrong. E.g. what if the client is not running?

Comment: You're not understanding my question. I'm not looking for advice on how to structure things in a Firebase scheme. It doesn't matter what I'm trying to achieve. I want to know how Firebase handles this particular scenario internally. Do they throttle updates to an entity for example? Or do they choose not to send all updates to connected clients? Etc etc.

Comment: I think this is a great question so I thought some testing was in order. I created a project that could run 10, 100, 1000 and 10,000 writes to a Firebase node, which was being observed by the app generating the writes and also an app on another device on another network. The results I received where that, other than network/internet latency, Firebase didn't miss a beat and responded to the writes effectively with 100% accuracy and no notable throttling. I would suggest sending a support question to Firebase to see under which situations throttling would come in to play, if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it's important to note that the Firebase realtime database is a state synchronization service, and is not a pub/sub service.

If you have a location that is updating rapidly, the service guarantees that eventually the state will be consistent across all clients, but not that all intermittent states will be surfaced. At most one event will fire for every update, but the server is free to 'squash' successive updates to the same location into one.

On the client making the updates, I think the current behavior is that every change propagates a local event, but I could be wrong and this is a notable exception.

In order to achieve guaranteed delivery of every intermediate state, it's possible to `push` (`childByAutoId` in Objective-C) onto a list of events at a database location instead of simply updating the value directly. Check out for the [Firebase REST API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-post) on saving lists of data

Comment: Of course there are networking/hardware constraints that limit the number of updates possible too